# Insert parameter into HTML using sql

Tags: html, sql

I have a sql job which runs once every 24 hours and sends an email with the data requested from my database tables. I'm inserting the data into :

```
DECLARE @ReportContentBuilder   table(LineSequence int identity, Line varchar(2000))
```

Like so :

```
INSERT INTO @ReportContentBuilder VALUES('<html>')
INSERT INTO @ReportContentBuilder VALUES('<head>')
INSERT INTO @ReportContentBuilder VALUES('<style type="text/css">')
INSERT INTO @ReportContentBuilder VALUES('body{font-family: Calibri; font-size: 10pt;}')
INSERT INTO @ReportContentBuilder VALUES('</style>')
INSERT INTO @ReportContentBuilder VALUES('</head>')
INSERT INTO @ReportContentBuilder VALUES('<body>')
```

Which is all good the email is sent and I receive all the data as expected. Its just my table headings are all the same.

```
WHILE (@MessageTypeCount > 0)
BEGIN
-- SET a parameter here to use as Id
    INSERT INTO @ReportContentBuilder VALUES('<table cellpadding="2" border="1">')
    INSERT INTO @ReportContentBuilder VALUES('<caption><b>Id</b></caption>')

-- Etc. etc. all the rest of the code works
END
```

I have a While loop and want to pass in a parameter into the **Id** section so the table heading will be different for each loop.

**Question:**

How do I pass a value into the Html part of the code to receive different table headings in my email?

I hope this is clear and I've added enough info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get this right, this will help (assuming MSSQL):

```
DECLARE @Id AS INT
SET @Id = 1

WHILE (@MessageTypeCount > 0)
BEGIN
-- SET a parameter here to use as Id

    INSERT INTO @ReportContentBuilder VALUES('<table cellpadding="2" border="1">')
    INSERT INTO @ReportContentBuilder VALUES('<caption><b>' + cast(@Id as VARCHAR(3)) + '</b></caption>')

    SET @Id = @Id + 1 /* Or SET @Id += 1 */
-- Etc. etc. all the rest of the code works
END
```

The variable `@Id` will serve as an example, where you will differentiate each run by an auto_increment value. In the second insert, you will break the literal string, concatenate it with the varchar value of `@Id` (if you don't convert or cast it, it might try to add a number to a string, and that'll surely break the script), and add the rest of the HTML after the Id.